# Recursive Fibonacci in Bash script

Tags: bash, fibonacci

This is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

function fibonacci(){

first=$1
second=$2

if (( first <= second ))
then
return 1

else 

return $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((second-2)) )
fi
}

echo $(fibonacci 2 0)
```

I think i'm having trouble with the else statement. I get the error `return: +: numeric argument required`
  on line 14.

The other problem that i'm having is that the script doesn't display any numbers even if i do `echo $(fibonacci 0 2)`. I thought it would display a 1 since i'm returning a 1 in that case. Can someone give me a couple of tips on how to accomplish this?

After checking out some of your answers this is my second attempt.. It works correctly except that it displays the nth fibonacci number in the form 1+1+1+1 etc. Any ideas why?

```
#!/bin/bash

function fibonacci(){

first=$1
second=$2

if (( first <= second ))
then
echo 1


else 

echo $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((first-2)) )
fi
}

val=$(fibonacci 3 0)
echo $val
```

My final attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

function fibonacci(){

first=$1

if (( first <= 0 ))
then
echo 1


else 

echo $(( $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((first-2)) ) ))
fi
}

val=$(fibonacci 5)
echo $val
```

thanks dudes.

Comment: If i remove the `(( ))` I get the error `first-1: command not found` and `second-1: command not found`

Comment: You can check your work against http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#UNIX_Shell

Comment: The unix return value (or exit status) in an int in the range (0..255). To return a value from a function, you have the function print to stdout, and the function call will look like `val=$(functionName arg ...)`

Comment: Getting exponential in bash? You have nothing to do? :)

Comment: Yeah i like to play around with different programming languages just for fun

Comment: `a=0;b=1;:(){echo $b;a=$((a+b));echo $a; b=$((a+b));:};:`

Comment: Pipe the above through `head -92` or fewer or things will get crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wumpus said you need to produce output using for example `echo`.
However you also need to fix the recursive invocation.
The outermost operation would be an addition, that is you want:

```
echo $(( a + b ))
```

Both `a` and `b` are substitutions of `fibonacci`, so

```
echo $(( $(fibonacci x) + $(fibonacci y) ))
```

`x` and `y` are in turn arithmetic expressions, so each needs its own `$(( ))`, giving:

```
echo $(( $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((second-2)) ) ))
```

If you are confused by this, you should put the components into temporary variables and break down the expression into parts.

As to the actual fibonacci, it's not clear why you are passing 2 arguments.

Comment: The second argument is just the number that will trigger the recursive base case. I made a mistake in my first attempt. `echo $(( $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((second-2)) ) ))` should have been `echo $(( $(fibonacci $((first-1)) ) + $(fibonacci $((first-2)) ) ))`

Comment: Oh dude, i think you just answered the question i just had about why i was getting 1+1+1+1 as output. Let me check and i'll update.. Update: Yes it totally worked. Thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

function fib(){
    if [ $1 -le 0 ]; then
        echo 0
    elif [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
        echo 1
    else
        echo $[`fib $[$1-2]` + `fib $[$1 - 1]` ]
    fi

}

fib $1
```

Comment: Please also comment on the code to be more educative.

Answer (score 2):

The `$(...)` substitution operator is replaced with the *output* of the command. Your function doesn't produce any output, so `$(...)` is the empty string.

Return values of a function go into `$?` just like exit codes of an external command.

So you need to either produce some output (make the function echo its result instead of returning it) or use `$?` after each call to get the value. I'd pick the echo.

Comment: The exit status is not intended for returning general data; i.e., `bash` functions are not intended to mimic mathematical functions. The exit code is intended solely to indicate whether or not the function succeeded. The correct way to communicate with the caller is either by writing to standard output, or (in distant second place) by setting global parameters.

Answer (score 0):

### Short version, recursive

```
fib(){(($1<2))&&echo $1||echo $(($(fib $(($1-1)))+$(fib $(($1-2)))));}
```

Answer (score 0):

While calculating fibonacci numbers with recursion is certainly possible, it has a terrible performance. A real bad example of the use of recursion: For every (sub) fibonacci number, two more fibonacci numbers must be calculated.

A much faster, and simple approach uses iteration, as can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136909/1516636

Answer (score 0):

This is correct for recursive solution

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function fib() {
    if [[ $1 == 0 ]]; then
        echo 0
    elif [[ $1 == 1 ]]; then
        echo 1
    else
        echo $(( $(fib "$(( $1-1 ))") + $(fib "$(( $1-2 ))") ))
    fi
}

#calc first 32 numbers in fib-ci sequence

for item in {1..32}
do
    echo $(fib $item)
done
```