# Fibonacci sequence calculator

Tags: linux, bash

I have an issue with some homework, so basically we were asked to create a bash script that takes a variable greater than 2 and gives back the same number of Fibonacci sequence numbers, i.o. if i were to give 5 it would print:
0 1 1 2 3
I have done some research and have come up with a unique idea i havent really seen anywhere online, (keep in mind i have some experience in python) but i have run into a problem, so basically i use a for expression in bash and 2 variables to calculate the sequence, i first manually set them to be 0 and 1 (the first and second numbers in the sequence) and then i add them together while changing their values,

So here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
b=1
for i in $(seq 1 $1);
do
  if ["$a" -gt "$b"]
  then 
    b=($a +$b)
    echo "$b"
  else
    a=($a +$b)
    echo $a
  fi
done
```

I have many issues and expect to be completely out of context but i hope you get the general idea and can help guide me through the problem :/
It seems like i want something to be treated as a number but its treated as text... Not sure though, any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Shellcheck produces [3 major findings](https://pastebin.com/kt4r48FE) for your code. You should fix them before continuing. Also see [Recursive Fibonacci in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17136505/608639) and friends.

Comment: you got some valid answers, why not take the time to thank for them by accepting and/or upvoting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, some small syntactic changes and new initial values make it work.

Notes:

- whitespace is important in bash, especially with special characters [ ] ;
- also, calculation with integer number can be forced using let

Nice idea to use a comparison to do the calculation with just two variables :)

```
#!/bin/bash - 
a=1
b=0
echo $a
for i in $(seq 1 $1);
do
    if [ $a -gt $b ] ; then
        let b=($a +$b)
        echo $b
    else
        let a=($a +$b)
        echo $a
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an arithmetic context in bash.

slight re-write can be

```
$ a=0; b=1; 
  for i in {1..9}; 
  do c=$((a+b)); 
     echo $c; 
     if ((a>b)); then b=$c; else a=$c; fi; 
  done

1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]
```

and you can do arithmetic evaluation using

```
b=$((a+b))
```

once the script runs, verify the result is what you are expecting (i.e. does it print 0?)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=0  
b=1
echo $a
c=$1
for i in $(seq 1 $((c-1)));
do
    if [ $a -gt $b ]; then
        b=$((a+b))
        echo $b
    else
        a=$((a+b))
        echo $a
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double parens to evaluate arithmetic expressions. Instead of:

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]
```

write:

```
if ((a > b))
```

and instead of:

```
($a + $b)
```

write:

```
$((a + b))
```

You can also write the `for` header this way:

```
for ((i = 0; i < $1; i++))
```

But this is not required in this case. Your loop then becomes:

```
for ((i = 0; i < $1; i++)); do
    if ((a > b)); then
        b=$((a + b))
        echo "$b"
    else
        a=$((a + b))
        echo "$a"
    fi
done
```